# JEE6 Producer for NewCookie

Tags: jboss7.x, java-ee-6, cdi

I would like to create a CDI producer for

```
javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie(java.lang.String name,
             java.lang.String value,
             java.lang.String path,
             java.lang.String domain,
             java.lang.String comment,
             int maxAge,
             boolean secure)
```

in such a way that the value will be different each time. I did some JEE6 a while ago but my memory is poor!

for ex. my producer for a simple logger is

```
@Produces
public Logger produceLogger(final InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {  
    final String injectingClass = injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName();
    logger.info("creating logger for : " + injectingClass);
    return Logger.getLogger(injectingClass);  
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: How much of the the cookie values do you want to pass to the producer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to calculate a unique value within a producer method without any additional parameters, then all you have to do is annotate a method with the return value `NewCookie`:

```
@Produces NewCookie createCookie() {
  // create cookie and its value  
}
```

If you need to create it subject to some external parameter, then this producer method can have parameters like any other method - but, all of these are injection points and must be obtainable by the container.

```
@Produces NewCookie createCookie(String value) {
  // create cookie with parameter value  
}
```

Now, a primitive type (as well as a String) has the problem, that you for sure have other instances of the same type with a different meaning, so you either use a special class like `MyValue` wrapping your String and use this as an injection point or annotate it with a custom annotation.

```
@Produces NewCookie createCookie(@CookieValue String value) {
  // create cookie with parameter value  
}
```

Then of course, you need again some place where this injected value is produced.

```
@Produces @CookieValue String createCookieValue() {
    // create value
}
```

Check out the [JavaEE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/index.html) or the [CDI Spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/) for more information.